# adding where clause in query with index slows down substantially

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with  640k records. There is a column called `COUNTRY_CD`. Its always set to `USA`. There is an index on the `COUNTRY_CD` column.

I ran the following query which took 6 sec

```
select sum(ga) from sales_data
```

Ran the following query which took 40 sec

```
Select sum(ga) from sales_data where country_cd='usa'
```

As i said that there is an index on `country_cd`. Why does it take so much time to run the second query?

---

Update:

i increased the innodb_buffer_pool_size. The first query now runs in 1 sec and the second in 6 sec. What more can i do. I really need them to be sub 1 second queries.

Comment: 40 seconds to process 640k rows is *very* slow.  Perhaps something else is happening on the database machine that is slowing things down.  Is it possible that your machine is severely memory limited, so only a fraction of the table can fit in memory?

Comment: nothing else going on. Its my dev server. No one else is using it. No other queries in the background. (i think even 6 seconds to sum 640k rows is slow but i might be wrong). The machine is only using 34% of memory so plenty of GB's of ram are free.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding your indexes?

Comment: just added them like 20 minutes ago

Comment: If your column only contains `USA`, then your index has an extremely low cardinality. Always remember that *low cardinality indexes have a negative impact on performances*.

Comment: Have you looked at [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) for both queries?

Comment: @pm 77-1 yes. For the first one it says that no indexes are used and for the second one it says that the country_cd index is being used.

Comment: I suggest you ask about attaining the desired speed on [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your overall performance is pretty slow, a reason for the difference could be the way, mysql is using indexes.

If you are running the query without a `where`-clause, mysql does a full table scan to sum up values. Usually mysql is now *reading* from the datatable in the order of insert, leading to *sequential disk i/o.* (fast)

When you are using the `where`-clause on an indexed column, mysql will use that index. So, it will start to process the index *sequentialy* but for every match, it will do a lookup of the `ga` value in the actual datatable, which then leads to *random disk i/o*

Here is a nice example, how sequential disk access can be way faster than using indexes (and random disk access): 
https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/11/23/full-table-scan-vs-full-index-scan-performance/

The example shows about the same relation (6 times slower) when using a very bad index - which your index is, if every data-row contains the same value.

The link also outlines, that this only matters if the table does not fit into memory (maybe your dev machine has not given enough memory to mysql?)

---

I just read through the comments there, big discussion about if there is really sequential disk-io possible. I cannot tell this for sure, but at least the results and the difference compared to in-memory operations are showing that the access of the FULL-TABLE **is** faster, than accessing the table based on indexes, if it has not yet been loaded to the memory.

Comment: I increased the innodb_buffer_pool_size. This reduced the run time to 1sec for the first query and 6 sec for the second query. Still the same 1:6 ratio. What more can i do?

Comment: @codeNinja Well, you could add an index on `(country_cd, ga)`. This would allow mysql to perform the operation purely based on index values, without having to fetch the `ga` value from the table.

Comment: @codeNinja can you also test how `Select sum(ga) from sales_data where country_cd='usa' GROUP BY country_cd` behaves?

Comment: (the index on `country_cd, ga` would be called *Covering Index* in case you want to do some research on that)